# php regular expression preg_match with html tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I write some simple code

```
$test='<span class="h2">AAAA</span> <div>aaaa</div> <p>ccc</p>';
preg_match('<\<(.*)>',$test,$matches);
echo $matches[0]
```

The result is :

> AAAA
>
> aaaa
>
> ccc

I could not understand why $matches[0] will be like that.

Could someone explain a little bit?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output then?

Comment: You can find more detailed info here http://www.noupe.com/development/php-regular-expressions.html

Comment: Stop it, the question has two problems: the output is not what the questioner thinks and the delimiters. No regex reference with the syntax of the regex itself helps any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the output you see in the browser. Check the HTML source or run from command line. What you really get is:

```
<span class="h2">AAAA</span> <div>aaaa</div> <p>ccc</p>
```

Why? Because `<>` is the [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) of your preg! So the actual regular expression is just `\<(.*)`, saying "give me a less than sign and then any number of anything." preg is greedy so it will consume as much as it can so that's why.

Comment: Do not think this is just a beginner's error: During Drupal 8 development a security hole was introduced (but [caught](https://drupal.org/node/2508654) before release) because we mixed up the `[]` for characters classes with `[]` as a preg delimiter. Bracket style delimiters are confusing and dangerous.